# How call setState from child widget*

Tags: flutter, dart, state

I have DefaultTabController with 3 tabs. One of the tabs is a list. I need that when clicking on a list item, current list change on other widget. How do I do this? Thank you. Tab State Class

```
class StationState extends State<Stations> {
  Widget secondWidget;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    secondWidget = Styles(this);
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000),
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: HeaderLogo(),
          backgroundColor: Color(0xFF000000),
          bottom: TabBar(
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            tabs: [
              Tab(
                text: 'Favorites',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Genres',
              ),
              Tab(
                text: 'Networks',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(children: [
          Favorites(),
          secondWidget,
          Networks(),
        ]),
      ),
    );

    ;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please add you code to help you better.

But you can pass a Callback to the list item, and when the list item is clicked, the callback is fired.

Something like this

```
return ListItem(
    onPressed: () {
        setState((){
            //Do what you need on the parent
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: The problem is that parent(DefaultTabController) and child(ListView) are located in different Classes

Comment: You need to give more detail about your issue then

Comment: I Changed the question. I need to change TabBarView child by clicking in the favorites () widget